# Python/Pandas:How to process a column of data when it meets certain criteria

Tags: python, regex, pandas

i have a csv lie this

```
userlabel|country
SZ5GZTD_[56][13631808]|russia
YZ5GZTC-3_[51][13680735]|uk
XZ5GZTA_12-[51][13574893]|usa
testYZ5GZWC_11-[51][13632101]|cuba
```

I use `pandas` to read this csv, I'd like to add a new column `ci`,Its value comes from  `userlabel`,and the following conditions must be met:

1. convert values to lowercase
2. start with 'yz' or 'testyz'

the code is like this :

```
(df['userlabel'].str.lower()).str.extract(r"(test)?([a-z]+).*", expand=True)[1]
```

when it matched,`ci` is the number between the first "- or _" and second "- or _" from `userlabel`.

the fake code is like this:

```
ci = (userlabel,r'.*(\_|\-)(\d+)(\_|\-).*',2)
```

finally,the result is like this

```
userlabel                      ci country
SZ5GZTD_[56][13631808]            russia
YZ5GZTC-3_[51][13680735]       3  uk
XZ5GZTA_12-[51][13574893]         usa
testYZ5GZWC_11-[51][13632101]  11 cuba
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'userlabel':['SZ5GZTD_[56][13631808]','YZ5GZTC-3_[51][13680735]','XZ5GZTA_12-[51][13574893]','testYZ5GZWC_11-[51][13632101]'], 'country':['russia','uk','usa','cuba']})
df['ci'] = df['userlabel'].str.extract(r"(?i)^(?:yz|testyz)[^_-]*[_-](\d+)[-_]", expand=True)
>>> df['ci']
0    NaN
1      3
2    NaN
3     11
Name: ci, dtype: object
# To rearrange columns, add the following line:
df = df[['userlabel', 'ci', 'country']]
>>> df
                       userlabel   ci country
0         SZ5GZTD_[56][13631808]  NaN  russia
1       YZ5GZTC-3_[51][13680735]    3      uk
2      XZ5GZTA_12-[51][13574893]  NaN     usa
3  testYZ5GZWC_11-[51][13632101]   11    cuba
```

**See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EEvLmT/1).**

*Regex details*:

- `(?i)` - make the pattern case insensitive (no need using `str.lower()`)
- `^` - start of string
- `(?:yz|testyz)` - a non-capturing group matching either `yz` or `testyz`
- `[^_-]*` - zero or more chars other than `_` and `-`
- `[_-]` - the first `_` or `-`
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (the `Series.str.extract` requires a capturing group since it only returns this captured substring): one or more digits
- `[-_]` - a `-` or `_`.

Answer (score 2):

```py
import re

def get_val(s):
    l = re.findall(r'^(YZ|testYZ).*[_-](\d+)[_-].*', s)
    return  None if(len(l) == 0) else l[0][1]

df['ci'] = df['userlabel'].apply(lambda x: get_val(x))
df = df[['userlabel', 'ci', 'country']]
```

```
userlabel                         ci    country
0   SZ5GZTD_[56][13631808]        None  russia
1   YZ5GZTC-3_[51][13680735]      3     uk
2   XZ5GZTA_12-[51][13574893]     None  usa
3   testYZ5GZWC_11-[51][13632101] 11    cuba
```

Comment: FYI: `[YZ|testYZ]` matches **1** character  in the set `X`, `Y`, `|`, `t`, `e`, `s`

Comment: @Toto is this okay now?

Comment: thank you very muck,it's works.if i don't want custom function like `def get_val(s)`,How to deal with it

Comment: Just 2 other remarks: 1) You can remove the pipe in `[_|-]`. 2) The `ci` column must be **before** `country`.

Comment: @cheryH you can use `str.extract` as shown in other answer by Wiktor Stribiżew